# Are there any positive definite adjacency matrices?

Tags: graph-theory, positive-definite, spectral-graph-theory

Let $A$ be the weighted adjacency matrix for an undirected graph with non-negative edge weights. Then $A$ is positive semi-definite.

Does a weighted adjacency matrix exist for one of these graphs that is strictly positive definite? How about if loops(edges from a node to itself) are not allowed?

Comment: if a matrix is positive definite, then its trace need to be positive. If no loops are allowed, the trace of the adjacency matrix is zero.

Comment: Could we show it by expanding the determinant down the diagonal terms? Then we would get zero, implying positive semi-definite.